# Why is there such a price difference between two seemingly identical drives

Tags: hard-disk

What's the difference between

- Seagate Expansion 5TB Desktop External Hard Drive USB 3.0 (STEB5000100)
  and
- 5TB USB 3.0 3,5 Seagate Expansion Desktop, STEB5000200 ?

The first is 50 % price of the second.

---

1. https://www.amazon.com/Seagate-Expansion-Deskt…/…/ref=sr_1_1
2. https://www.amazon.com/Seagate-Expansion-Deskt…/…/ref=sr_1_1

Comment: Holy heck is this even a question? a statement?

Comment: It's a normal question, I am buying a 5TB disk and I wonder why one is 2x cheaper than the other. That's not a technical support. If that's not a legible question here, I will vote to close this beta as useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Seagate's [**data sheet**](http://www.seagate.com/www-content/product-content/expansion-fam/expansion-external/en-us/docs/expansion-desktop-hard-drive-ds1843-2-1502us.pdf), I've noticed 3 things:

1. The only thing different across different models (with different serial numbers) is the capacity.
2. STEB5000200 is marketed for EMEA region (Europe, middle east and africa), while STEB5000100 is for America (NA I would suppose).
3. They both have 5TB capacity so there shouldn't be any obvious technical differences, apart from marketing, quota and maybe import tax.

Comment: The difference is the warranty. I've asked in Seagate directly and they told me.